# Simultaneously Transforming and Summarizing a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

So I have a table containing the following data

|  | Type | Year | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | 2016 | 50.079 | 14.425 |
| 2 | Y | 2017 | 50.079 | 14.425 |
| 3 | Y | 2022 | 50.079 | 14.425 |
| 4 | Z | 2017 | 50.079 | 14.425 |
| 5 | Y | 2018 | 50.079 | 14.425 |

I want to transform it into something like this

| 2016 | 50.079 | 50.080 | 50.081 | 50.082 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14.425 | 1X2Y | Y1Z | 4X | 1X2Y |
| 14.426 | 2Y | 1X2Y | Y1Z | Y |
| 14.427 | Y1Z | Y1Z | 1X2Y | Z |
| 14.428 | Z | 2Z | 2Y | 2Y |
| 14.429 | X | Z | 1X2Y | 2Y |

So that for each year i have a separate table where i can see how many of each type have the same coordinates.

I have managed to create separate tables for each year that look like this:

`View(Matrices_by_year$`2018`)`

|  | Latitude | Longitude | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50.079 | 14.425 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 50.078 | 14.425 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 50.077 | 14.425 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 50.076 | 14.425 | 1 | 0 | 4 |

Which sorta conveys the same information but not in a way i want.
I am mainly struggling with the part where i need to add the numbers in X/Y/Z together in one cell without losing The reference of what type they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay slightly hard to follow exactly what you want but I've given it a shot. Firstly its best to provide your data using `dput(your_data)` or dput(head(your_data))` as its easier for others to then read it in to their R.

I have assumed your data is a dataframe even though you called it a matrix. Converting between them shouldn't be hard. Also I've started from the final table you displayed. Basically I just pivoted to longer form so the column names (X, Y, Z) were easily accessible, and then you can just paste them all together by the location. This does give you 0s where there are none. If that is undesirable you could filter out lines with a 0 `value` prior to grouping and summarising.

```r
    library(tidyr)
    library(dplyr)

test <- read.table(text = " Latitude    Longitude   X   Y   Z
1   50.079  14.425  1   0   1
2   50.078  14.425  2   3   0
3   50.077  14.425  0   1   0
4   50.076  14.425  1   0   4")


test %>% pivot_longer(c(X,Y,Z)) %>% 
  group_by(Latitude, Longitude) %>% 
  summarise(out = paste0(value, name, collapse = "")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Latitude, values_from = out)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Latitude'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 1 x 5
#>   Longitude `50.076` `50.077` `50.078` `50.079`
#>       <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
#> 1      14.4 1X0Y4Z   0X1Y0Z   2X3Y0Z   1X0Y1Z
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi, sorry for the matrix/dataframe confusion i am new to R and still kinda figuring it out. What you wrote worked well, however for some reaon i can only see the first 50 columns? i can see all the 393 rows so i am not sure why it would cut off the columns?

Comment: just for clarification I am aware that the viewer only supports 50 rows at a time. when i try to look at other columns it only gives me the 50th

Comment: @CihlaFace Hmm I don't know, you can definitely pivot_wider is not limited to a number of columns (or at least, not 50, I just checked with 100x100) what do you get if you do `dim(output)` or `output[,45:60]` or maybe export it to a csv so you can see more than 50 columns. Is it possible you only have 50 latitudes?

Comment: I somehow solved it by forcing R to show View() for more columns, I am still not sure what went wrong, because even when i exported it as csv i only got 50 columns, but after forcing it to show more it gave me the whole thing

Comment: Glad you got it working, if you are happy with it please mark it as an accepted answer